# Springboot 2.3.4.RELEASE connection to Azure postgresql fails

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

We upgraded one of our services to 2.3.4.RELEASE lately. After the update, we are no longer able to connect to Azure PAAS PostgreSQL, we receive
**Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://postgisdb:5432/someDb) for user 'someUser@someDB': The connection attempt failed**
We saw that the PostgreSQL dependency was updated from 4.2.14 to 4.2.16. Switching back to 4.2.14 made the issue disappear, but nevertheless, I would like to know why it fails on the current version.

Comment: the postgresql dependency was updated from 4.2.14 to 4.2.14?

Comment: Sorry, of course, that's wrong. I did edit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Appending `gssEncMode=disable` to the connection string fixes the problem. We tried it and it worked for us.
For further details, check the [github](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1867) page

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Appending gssEncMode=disable to the connection string fixes the problem.

> jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:5432/db-user?gssEncMode=disable